# Cordova android emulator doesnt open

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator, phonegap-build

I have created new Cordova project as following:

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
cd hello
cordova platform add android
cordova emulate android
```

and it doent open the emulator:

```
C:\Users\Ortal\Desktop\hello> cordova emulate android
Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Users\Ortal\Desktop\hello\platforms\android\cord
ova\run.bat --emulator""
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Ortal\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_05
WARNING : no emulator specified, defaulting to Nexus_5_API_22_x86
Waiting for emulator...
```

Comment: Give GenyMotion a try

Comment: Do you have any Real Device connected with the PC ?

Comment: Can you launch the emulator manually?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in earlier comment, Genymotion is a great and fast tool for android emulator. This [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5MypWPkXaDw) may help you install Genymotion.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to Install one or more Intel x86 Atom System Images as well as the Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager, available under Extras for the cordova to run app in emulator.

But i recommend you open the emulator manually or use Genymotion cause it is very faster than default android emulators.

Answer (score 0):

I never got it to work, I had to compile it and launch it right from eclipse always

Answer (score 0):

It's not working for me... too

Use Phonegap build...  https://build.phonegap.com/

r

Export the android project into eclipse and check the output.

Answer (score 0):

Check for all of these:

1. You don't have **Bluestacks** or any similar software installed. If you do, you'll need to uninstall it.
2. Your PATH variable contains paths to Android SDK Tools and Android Platform Tools.
3. You can manually launch the emulator from AVD Manager.